# Ancient Saharan Artifacts

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

My respected colleague Dr. Henry just returned from an expedition in the Sahara.

He was hoping to find evidence of a sophisticated ancient civilization, but had little success. However, his team did discover several small artifacts, all in the same area:

[image: Ancient artifacts]

I wonder if these artifacts served any purpose. And if so, what?

---

**Update**

Hint 1:

> If the Saharan civilization was as sophisticated as Dr. Henry believes, they must have developed very advanced mathematics.

Hint 2:

> There are exactly two different symbols. What can this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

> Pi in binary. http://www.befria.nu/elias/pi/binpi.html
>  The two dots in the center represent the integer part, the marks at the circumference represent the fractional part.

Comment: Remember to add the significance (just in case) - pi is related to the **circle** as it is the ratio of the circumference to the diameter.

Answer (score 17):

After spending many hours in a haze of glue fumes...

> Clearly it's a frisbee! 
> [image: The assembled artifact]

Comment: Or perhaps some type of sun dial?

Comment: @Gamow How do you intend to read a sundial while it's spinning through the air towards you? :D

Comment: @Gamow Realistically though, fair point although I'm not sure what the spacing should look like at the equator. There are 15 marks around the ring; 7 dots and 8 circles: oo.oo.oooo.....

Comment: @Samthere Poor Dr. Henry... he really was hoping to find something extraordinary. I guess a Frisbee is something too

Comment: looking at this as a clock face, can you swap the piece at about 1 with the similarly-shaped wedge at about 9? That would keep the oo. pattern going a little longer and might reveal something about the places where the pattern isn't followed

Comment: @KateGregory I used something other than Word to put it together better now that I'm home. The two wedge pieces are actually quite different in size; I don't think there's a different way to rearrange it.

Comment: Looks like 17 spots around the ring, 2 unmarked.

Comment: @deepthought Actually it's 16 spots, 1 unmarked.

Comment: It would have been great if all the marks were on the outer part of the circle

Comment: It's an early basketball design, made on a clay plate, but someone misunderstood the difference between blueprint and finished product and dunked it. The elders then decided they needed to focus on education, so basketball had to wait another 4500 years to be re-invented.

Comment: So this is not the intended answer?

Comment: @Raystafarian the assembled image is correct, but the symbols have not yet been deciphered. I might need to post a hint.